# Google radar chart not rendering when more than 2 columns of input is given

Tags: php, google-visualization

Hi I am trying to use google radar charts in my android app my goal was I am trying to send the user name to PHP file and From PHP file I would like to  retrieve the data from from the database and display the chart. I am do it sucessfully but my I am unable render the chart can any one tell me the problem to solve it.

I FOUND PROBLEM REGARDING RENDERING THE GRAPH WHEN I GIVE INPUT MORE THAN COLUMNS AS SHOWN BELONG I AM UNABLE TO RENDER THE GRAPH.

THIS INPUT IS WORKING
              [100,10],
              [80,20],
              [60,30],
              [30,40],
              [25,50],
              [20,60],
              [10,70],

THIS TYPE OF INPUT IS NOT WORKING

```
          [100,10,30],
          [80,20,30],
          [60,30,30],
          [30,40,30],
          [25,50,50],
          [20,60,60],
          [10,70,80],


<html>
 <head>
    <title></title>      
 </head>  
 <?php  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "innernet") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
        mysql_select_db("mobiledb", $con);       
        //$sth = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `Q1`, `Q2` FROM `table2` WHERE `id`=8710058770");        
        $user= $_POST["user"];
        echo "$user";
        $response["cols"] = array();    
       // $news = array();
        //$news["id"] = "";
        //$news["label"] = "ID";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "string";                                           

        //array_push($response["cols"], $news);

        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q1a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);

        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q1b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q2a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q2b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news); 
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q3a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q3b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q4a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q4b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q5a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q5b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q6a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q6b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q7a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q7b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q8a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q8b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
        $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q9a";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);       
         $news = array();

        $news["label"] = "Q9b";                                           
        //$news["type"] = "number";                                           

        array_push($response["cols"], $news);
       // $news = array();
      //  $news["id"] = "";
        //$news["label"] = "ts";                                           
      //  $news["type"] = "number";                                           

       // array_push($response["cols"], $news);       


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT  `Q1a`, `Q1b`, `Q2a`, `Q2b`, `Q3a`, `Q3b`, `Q4a`, `Q4b`, `Q5a`, `Q5b`, `Q6a`, `Q6b`, `Q7a`, `Q7b`, `Q8a`, `Q8b`, `Q9a`, `Q9b` FROM goaltest WHERE id='test'") or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {       
            $response["rows"] = array();    $table = array();   $rows = array();  
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {        
                $temp = array();           
                //$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['id']);          
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q1a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q1b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q2a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q2b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q3a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q3b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q4a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q4b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q5a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q5b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q6a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q6b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q7a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q7b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q8a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q8b']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q9a']);
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q9b']);
                //$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['ts']);

                array_push($response["rows"], array('c' => $temp));                                      
            }            
            echo json_encode($response);             
        }



    ?>

    <!--Load the AJAX API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {


        var response = '<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>';     alert(' hi ' + response);            
        var obj = eval ("(" + response + ")");  
           var options = {cht: 'rs', chco: '00FF00,FF00FF', chg: '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0', chm: 'B,FF000080,0,1.0,5.0|B,FF990080,1,1.0,5.0'};
            // Chart API chart type 'rs' is radar chart
            options.cht = 'rs';

            // set the line colors
            //options.colors = ['#00FF00' , '#FF00FF'];

            // fill the area under the lines
            options.fill = true;

            // create a grid for the chart
            //options.chg = '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0';


            var dataTable = google.visualization.DataTable(response);


            var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code which is rendered.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title></title>      
 </head>  
 {"cols":[{"label":"Q1a"},{"label":"Q1b"},{"label":"Q2a"},{"label":"Q2b"},{"label":"Q3a"},{"label":"Q3b"},{"label":"Q4a"},{"label":"Q4b"},{"label":"Q5a"},{"label":"Q5b"},{"label":"Q6a"},{"label":"Q6b"},{"label":"Q7a"},{"label":"Q7b"},{"label":"Q8a"},{"label":"Q8b"},{"label":"Q9a"},{"label":"Q9b"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":12},{"v":34},{"v":132},{"v":3},{"v":23},{"v":23},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":14},{"v":14},{"v":13},{"v":21},{"v":12},{"v":12},{"v":12},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":10},{"v":52},{"v":16},{"v":61},{"v":9},{"v":31},{"v":20},{"v":48},{"v":18},{"v":64},{"v":38},{"v":64},{"v":19},{"v":56},{"v":35},{"v":57},{"v":37},{"v":55}]}]}
    <!--Load the AJAX API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {


        var response = '{"cols":[{"label":"Q1a"},{"label":"Q1b"},{"label":"Q2a"},{"label":"Q2b"},{"label":"Q3a"},{"label":"Q3b"},{"label":"Q4a"},{"label":"Q4b"},{"label":"Q5a"},{"label":"Q5b"},{"label":"Q6a"},{"label":"Q6b"},{"label":"Q7a"},{"label":"Q7b"},{"label":"Q8a"},{"label":"Q8b"},{"label":"Q9a"},{"label":"Q9b"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":12},{"v":34},{"v":132},{"v":3},{"v":23},{"v":23},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":14},{"v":14},{"v":13},{"v":21},{"v":12},{"v":12},{"v":12},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":10},{"v":52},{"v":16},{"v":61},{"v":9},{"v":31},{"v":20},{"v":48},{"v":18},{"v":64},{"v":38},{"v":64},{"v":19},{"v":56},{"v":35},{"v":57},{"v":37},{"v":55}]}]}';     alert(' hi ' + response);            
        var obj = eval ("(" + response + ")");  
           var options = {cht: 'rs', chco: '00FF00,FF00FF', chg: '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0', chm: 'B,FF000080,0,1.0,5.0|B,FF990080,1,1.0,5.0'};
            // Chart API chart type 'rs' is radar chart
            options.cht = 'rs';

            // set the line colors
            //options.colors = ['#00FF00' , '#FF00FF'];

            // fill the area under the lines
            options.fill = true;

            // create a grid for the chart
            //options.chg = '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0';


            var dataTable = google.visualization.DataTable(response);


            var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: seems you're talking about a web page loading in Android App. Any JavaScript error? Can you show the resultant JavaScript codes ?

Comment: First I am trying to run in normal web browser.

Comment: Correct approach, so is there any error? and the resultant JS codes?

Comment: Yes i HAVE AN ERROR i AM UNABLE TO GENERATE THE OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the wrong chart library:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

should be:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['imagechart']});
```

Also, you have a trailing comma at the end of your options array, which you should remove:

```
var options = {cht: 'rs', chco: '00FF00,FF00FF', chg: '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0', chm: 'B,FF000080,0,1.0,5.0|B,FF990080,1,1.0,5.0'};
```

You can simplify your handling of the JSON as well, as there is no need to input it as a string and then eval it - you can just use the output as is:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>);
```

Edit:

There are a few more things you should do.  First, remove this line:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

from the PHP section at the top, as it is printing out the json string into your HTML where you don't want it.  Second, move the script tag for your javascript into either the `<head>` or `<body>` elements, as `<script>` is not a valid child of `<html>`.  Third, you are missing the `new` keyword in front of the DataTable constructor:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);
```

Those adjustments should fix it you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions but after trying all your suggestions but I am unable render the graph it is just showing me the white page. and I tried to inspect the page but could not find any error.

Comment: Post the javascript as rendered in the browser (open the page in a browser, view source, and copy it) and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi I have added the rendered java script code. please take a look.

Comment: Edited my response above.

Comment: Sorry, I left the comment before making the edit, check again.