# Getting different output charts when compared with Google charts and Excel

Tags: google-visualization

I am using [Google Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chart_API) for displaying a radar chart for my data calling from a database, but I am getting the wrong chart evident from comparing an Excel chart and a Google generated chart.

Here is the Excel chart:

[image]

Here is the output from the Google Chart API:

[image]

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawVisualization() {
            var response = '<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>';     //alert(' hi ' + response);
            var obj = eval ("(" + response + ")");
            var options = {cht: 'rs', chxt :'x,y', chd: 't:Q1a|Q1b|Q2a|Q2b|Q3a|Q3b|Q4a|Q4b|Q5a|Q5b|Q6a|Q6b|Q7a|Q7b|Q8a|Q8b|Q9a|Q9b',chls:'3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3' };
            // Chart API chart type 'rs' is radar chart
            //options.cht = 'rs';
            //options.chx1 = 'Q1,Q2,Q,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9';
            //options.chxl = '0:|Q1a|Q1b|Q2a|Q2b|Q3a|Q3b|Q4a|Q4b|Q5a|Q5b|Q6a|Q6b|Q7a|Q7b|Q8a|Q8b|Q9a|Q9b';
            //0:|0|45|90|135|180|225|270|315
            // Set the line colors
            //options.colors = ['#00FF00' , '#FF00FF'];

            // Fill the area under the lines
            options.fill = true;

            // Create a grid for the chart
            //options.chg = '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0';

            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);

            var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('Visualization'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

    <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `json_encode` response output is:

```
var response = '{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Q1a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q1b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q2a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q2b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q3a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q3b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q4a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q4b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q5a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q5b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q6a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q6b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q7a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q7b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q8a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q8b","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q9a","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Q9b","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":12},{"v":34},{"v":132},{"v":3},{"v":23},{"v":23},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":13},{"v":14},{"v":14},{"v":13},{"v":21},{"v":12},{"v":12},{"v":12},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":10},{"v":52},{"v":16},{"v":61},{"v":9},{"v":31},{"v":20},{"v":48},{"v":18},{"v":64},{"v":38},{"v":64},{"v":19},{"v":56},{"v":35},{"v":57},{"v":37},{"v":55}]},{"c":[{"v":43},{"v":26},{"v":28},{"v":63},{"v":36},{"v":59},{"v":33},{"v":69},{"v":33},{"v":64},{"v":30},{"v":67},{"v":40},{"v":68},{"v":36},{"v":40},{"v":39},{"v":68}]},{"c":[{"v":44},{"v":76},{"v":73},{"v":83},{"v":71},{"v":69},{"v":53},{"v":80},{"v":39},{"v":70},{"v":63},{"v":82},{"v":33},{"v":80},{"v":33},{"v":76},{"v":36},{"v":75}]}]}';
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
   <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>      
 </head>  
 <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "innernet") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("mobiledb", $con);
$user= $_GET['user'];

$response["cols"] = array(array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'Q'));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  `Q1a`, `Q1b`, `Q2a`, `Q2b`, `Q3a`, `Q3b`, `Q4a`, `Q4b`, `Q5a`, `Q5b`, `Q6a`, `Q6b`, `Q7a`, `Q7b`, `Q8a`, `Q8b`, `Q9a`, `Q9b` FROM goaltest WHERE id='$user'") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["rows"] = array();
    $table = array();
    // set up rows
    $rows = array (
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q1a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q1b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q2a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q2b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q3a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q3b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q4a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q4b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q5a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q5b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q6a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q6b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q7a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q7b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q8a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q8b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q9a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q9b')))
    );
    for ($i == 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++) {
        // add a new series for this row
        $response["cols"][] = array('type' => 'number', 'label' => "Series $i");

        // fill in the data for each Q
        $rows[0]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q1a']);
        $rows[1]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q1b']);
        $rows[2]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q2a']);
        $rows[3]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q2b']);
        $rows[4]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q3a']);
        $rows[5]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q3b']);
        $rows[6]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q4a']);
        $rows[7]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q4b']);
        $rows[8]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q5a']);
        $rows[9]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q5b']);
        $rows[10]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q6a']);
        $rows[11]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q6b']);
        $rows[12]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q7a']);
        $rows[13]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q7b']);
        $rows[14]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q8a']);
        $rows[15]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q8b']);
        $rows[16]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q9a']);
        $rows[17]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q9b']);

         array_push($response["rows"], array('c' => $rows)); 


    }
}

echo json_encode($response); 
?>

    <!--Load the AJAX API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {


        var response = '<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>';     //alert(' hi ' + response);            
        var obj = eval ("(" + response + ")");  
            var options = {
        cht: 'rs',
        chxt :'x,y',
        chxl: 't:Q1a|Q1b|Q2a|Q2b|Q3a|Q3b|Q4a|Q4b|Q5a|Q5b|Q6a|Q6b|Q7a|Q7b|Q8a|Q8b|Q9a|Q9b'


    };

            // create a grid for the chart
            //options.chg = '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0';


            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);



            var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is javascript after changing my php code

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title></title>      
 </head>  
 {"cols":[{"type":"string","label":"Q"},{"type":"number","label":"Series "},{"type":"number","label":"Series 1"},{"type":"number","label":"Series 2"},{"type":"number","label":"Series 3"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23}]}]},{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12},{"v":10}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34},{"v":52}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3},{"v":61}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23},{"v":31}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13},{"v":20}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13},{"v":48}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13},{"v":18}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13},{"v":64}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14},{"v":38}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14},{"v":64}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13},{"v":19}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21},{"v":56}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12},{"v":35}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12},{"v":57}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12},{"v":37}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23},{"v":55}]}]},{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12},{"v":10},{"v":43}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34},{"v":52},{"v":26}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132},{"v":16},{"v":28}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3},{"v":61},{"v":63}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23},{"v":9},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23},{"v":31},{"v":59}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13},{"v":20},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13},{"v":48},{"v":69}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13},{"v":18},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13},{"v":64},{"v":64}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14},{"v":38},{"v":30}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14},{"v":64},{"v":67}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13},{"v":19},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21},{"v":56},{"v":68}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12},{"v":35},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12},{"v":57},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12},{"v":37},{"v":39}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23},{"v":55},{"v":68}]}]},{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12},{"v":10},{"v":43},{"v":44}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34},{"v":52},{"v":26},{"v":76}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132},{"v":16},{"v":28},{"v":73}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3},{"v":61},{"v":63},{"v":83}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23},{"v":9},{"v":36},{"v":71}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23},{"v":31},{"v":59},{"v":69}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13},{"v":20},{"v":33},{"v":53}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13},{"v":48},{"v":69},{"v":80}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13},{"v":18},{"v":33},{"v":39}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13},{"v":64},{"v":64},{"v":70}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14},{"v":38},{"v":30},{"v":63}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14},{"v":64},{"v":67},{"v":82}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13},{"v":19},{"v":40},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21},{"v":56},{"v":68},{"v":80}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12},{"v":35},{"v":36},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12},{"v":57},{"v":40},{"v":76}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12},{"v":37},{"v":39},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23},{"v":55},{"v":68},{"v":75}]}]}]}
    <!--Load the AJAX API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {


        var response = '{"cols":[{"type":"string","label":"Q"},{"type":"number","label":"Series "},{"type":"number","label":"Series 1"},{"type":"number","label":"Series 2"},{"type":"number","label":"Series 3"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23}]}]},{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12},{"v":10}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34},{"v":52}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3},{"v":61}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23},{"v":31}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13},{"v":20}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13},{"v":48}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13},{"v":18}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13},{"v":64}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14},{"v":38}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14},{"v":64}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13},{"v":19}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21},{"v":56}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12},{"v":35}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12},{"v":57}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12},{"v":37}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23},{"v":55}]}]},{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12},{"v":10},{"v":43}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34},{"v":52},{"v":26}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132},{"v":16},{"v":28}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3},{"v":61},{"v":63}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23},{"v":9},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23},{"v":31},{"v":59}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13},{"v":20},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13},{"v":48},{"v":69}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13},{"v":18},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13},{"v":64},{"v":64}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14},{"v":38},{"v":30}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14},{"v":64},{"v":67}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13},{"v":19},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21},{"v":56},{"v":68}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12},{"v":35},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12},{"v":57},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12},{"v":37},{"v":39}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23},{"v":55},{"v":68}]}]},{"c":[{"c":[{"v":"Q1a"},{"v":12},{"v":10},{"v":43},{"v":44}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q1b"},{"v":34},{"v":52},{"v":26},{"v":76}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2a"},{"v":132},{"v":16},{"v":28},{"v":73}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q2b"},{"v":3},{"v":61},{"v":63},{"v":83}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3a"},{"v":23},{"v":9},{"v":36},{"v":71}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q3b"},{"v":23},{"v":31},{"v":59},{"v":69}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4a"},{"v":13},{"v":20},{"v":33},{"v":53}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q4b"},{"v":13},{"v":48},{"v":69},{"v":80}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5a"},{"v":13},{"v":18},{"v":33},{"v":39}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q5b"},{"v":13},{"v":64},{"v":64},{"v":70}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6a"},{"v":14},{"v":38},{"v":30},{"v":63}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q6b"},{"v":14},{"v":64},{"v":67},{"v":82}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7a"},{"v":13},{"v":19},{"v":40},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q7b"},{"v":21},{"v":56},{"v":68},{"v":80}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8a"},{"v":12},{"v":35},{"v":36},{"v":33}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q8b"},{"v":12},{"v":57},{"v":40},{"v":76}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9a"},{"v":12},{"v":37},{"v":39},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Q9b"},{"v":23},{"v":55},{"v":68},{"v":75}]}]}]}';     //alert(' hi ' + response);            
        var obj = eval ("(" + response + ")");  
            var options = {
        cht: 'rs',
        chxt :'x,y',
        chxl: 't:Q1a|Q1b|Q2a|Q2b|Q3a|Q3b|Q4a|Q4b|Q5a|Q5b|Q6a|Q6b|Q7a|Q7b|Q8a|Q8b|Q9a|Q9b'


    };

            // create a grid for the chart
            //options.chg = '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0';


            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);



            var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `echo json_encode($response);` output?

Comment: I have added the json encode output

Comment: The sample HTML is not valid. Everything should be inside the *body* and *head* elements. It is a good idea to use [an HTML validator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the code you are using, I would guess that your data is organized like this:

```
Q1a    | Q1b    | Q2a    | Q2b    | ... | Q9b    |
-------|--------|--------|--------|-----|--------|
<data> | <data> | <data> | <data> | ... | <data> |
<data> | <data> | <data> | <data> | ... | <data> |
```

What you need to do is pivot the data into a structure like this:

```
Q    | Reeks1 | Reeks2 |
-----|--------|--------|
Q1a  | <data> | <data> |
Q1b  | <data> | <data> |
Q2a  | <data> | <data> |
Q2b  | <data> | <data> |
...
Q9b  | <data> | <data> |
```

Edit:

I wrote a jsfiddle example that uses a DataTable in the correct format for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/LjmPA/

Edit 2:

Try this for your PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "innernet") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("mobiledb", $con);
$user= $_GET['user'];

$response["cols"] = array(array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'Q'));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  `Q1a`, `Q1b`, `Q2a`, `Q2b`, `Q3a`, `Q3b`, `Q4a`, `Q4b`, `Q5a`, `Q5b`, `Q6a`, `Q6b`, `Q7a`, `Q7b`, `Q8a`, `Q8b`, `Q9a`, `Q9b` FROM goaltest WHERE id='$user'") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $table = array();
    // set up rows
    $rows = array (
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q1a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q1b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q2a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q2b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q3a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q3b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q4a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q4b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q5a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q5b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q6a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q6b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q7a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q7b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q8a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q8b'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q9a'))),
        array('c' => array(array('v' => 'Q9b')))
    );
    for ($i == 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++) {
        // add a new series for this row
        $response["cols"][] = array('type' => 'number', 'label' => "Series $i");

        // fill in the data for each Q
        $rows[0]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q1a']);
        $rows[1]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q1b']);
        $rows[2]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q2a']);
        $rows[3]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q2b']);
        $rows[4]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q3a']);
        $rows[5]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q3b']);
        $rows[6]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q4a']);
        $rows[7]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q4b']);
        $rows[8]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q5a']);
        $rows[9]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q5b']);
        $rows[10]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q6a']);
        $rows[11]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q6b']);
        $rows[12]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q7a']);
        $rows[13]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q7b']);
        $rows[14]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q8a']);
        $rows[15]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q8b']);
        $rows[16]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q9a']);
        $rows[17]['c'][] = array('v' => (int) $row['Q9b']);
    }
    $response["rows"] = $rows;
}
?>
```

I can't test this code, so there may be bugs, but it should give you a basic idea of one way to pivot the data.

Comment: ok here I am uploading my code. And But if I change data structure in excel also I was getting the same output.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same output in the Google radar chart if you pivot the data like this.

Comment: The code you posted above is not pivoted - it still has the "Q" values as columns instead of rows.

Comment: Hey can kindly tell me how to do that I could find the right tutorial for doing it.

Comment: Are you still using the PHP code posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056049/google-radar-chart-not-rendering-when-more-than-2-columns-of-input-is-given) on the server-side?

Comment: @user2614247, I edited my answer above with PHP code for you to try.

Comment: Sorry for late reply I have seen yesterday itself and I was trying to do but I am not succeded I am not getting graph drawn. Here I have uploaded my data

Comment: I forgot to include the line that adds the rows to the output (`$response["rows"] = $rows;`), and you added in an extra line that should not be there (`array_push($response["rows"], array('c' => $rows));`).  I updated my code above.  Fix those and see if it works.